# Mysql query for fetching the leave taken by a person

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure

```
leave_id    int(10)     No           
user_id     int(10)     No           
leavetype_id    int(15)     No           
fromdt  date    No           
todt    date    No           
no_of_days  varchar(10)     No           
status  enum('0', '1', '2', '3')    No           
modifier    varchar(35)     No           
modifiedby  varchar(25)     No           
description     varchar(100)
```

which contains data like this

```
leave_id        194
user_id     2
leavetype_id    2
fromdt          2011-04-26
todt            2011-05-09
no_of_days  9
status          3
modifier     
modifiedby   
description     some description
```

Now I need to search based on the leave date.  For eg I want to see the leaves a user taken f( for eg user_id = 2) between  2011-04-27 and 2011-05-08.  As you can see, as per the result posted above the user_id 2 was on leave from 2011-04-26 to 2011-05-09.  And the given date 2011-04-27 and 2011-05-08 comes between that.

I have tried the following things

- Between AND
- Less than Greater than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will show any leave that has at least 1 day in common with the period between `'2011-04-27'` and `'2011-05-08'` :

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE fromdt <= '2011-05-08'
  AND todt >= '2011-04-27'
```

This will show the leaves that spanned the whole period `'2011-04-27'` to `'2011-05-08'` :

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE fromdt <= '2011-04-27' 
  AND todt >= '2011-05-08'
```

Comment: Just note that it will also include leaves that started earlier (say in March) and ended in the period `04-27 to 05-08` and also leaves that started in the period and ended later.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you're after:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE fromdt < '2011-04-27'
AND todt >  '2011-05-08'
```